# Shifting the noise to one end of an object using nodes?

Tags: shader-nodes

I am still fairly new to Blender. Although I came from Lightwave there are still plenty of things I am figuring out.

This one seems like it should be pretty easy but I am not sure where to even start looking for my solution.

I am making a paint brush and I want the tip to be darker than the section near the metal ring holding the brush to the handle. I have used a color ramp to get my colors and a noise texture to spread the colors around. The texture coord node and mapping node let me stretch the colors along the brush to make streaks instead of splotches.

What I can't figure out is how do I get the dark color to appear near the tip more often and the light color to appear near the metal ring more often still giving a variety of colors but concentrated to the ends.

Any suggestions on what to try to do this?

What I have now...
[image: Brush]
[image: Nodes]

What I am trying to do...
[image: Want]

Here is sort of what I am after. Not exact but gives the concept. See how the brush still has strands but the darker area is focused near the tip? I just want to weight the randomness to lean darker to the tip and lighter to the base.

[image: want2]

THANK YOU FOR YOUR ADVICE!

---

UPDATE! Although the answer from Onyx wasn't quite enough, it set me on the path I needed to get mostly to where I wanted to be. I still have some tweaking but I have the basic concept now.

In short, I took two color ramp nodes and mixed them together. One had the noise I wanted and the other used the texture coord and mapping nodes to get the rotation. The two ramps are similar in color but not the same. There is a third color ramp off screen but it is only used for the bump map for the brush fibers and not relative to this rotating of the color mappings I was after.

[image: finished]
[image: nodes]

Thanks for helping me on my way!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a Gradient Texture (Shift-A > Texture). You may need to play with the mapping to rotate the gradient and/or use another colour ramp node to refine it, but you can basically use the output of this to influence your colours.

ETA: If you have the Node Wrangler add-on enabled (it's shipped with Blender), you can ctrl-shift-click a node to see just its effect on the object. I'd use this while refining and mapping your gradient texture to make sure it's set up correctly.

Comment: The gradient texture doesn't really seem very useful. It is the same as a color ramp but with no flexibility. I managed to get it applied but it was not even close to working correctly and only offered a solid shading. Maybe I am not understanding what you are suggesting.

Comment: Basically, I have the "brush" feel that I am after but I need to add something that pushes the darker tones to the tip and the lighter tones to the base while leaving the strands feeling in place. I tried an RGB mix node but that just made things muddy.

Comment: I just added a picture to the bottom of my original message giving a better example of what I am after.

Comment: Thanks for getting me going in the right direction. I updated my question to show the final product. Not perfectly what I am after but very close and now I have the concept.